# How do I swap two words in a string without using additional arrays or strings?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I cannot use additional arrays or strings, because these are the rules my professor set.

Example: `"Apple and pear"` -> `"pear and Apple"`.

I managed to swap the words but only if they are the same length. The problem comes when we have 2 words with 2 different lengths.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define max 255
//pear meat
void swapWords(char* string, int start, int end){
    int nstart, nend; //next start, and end
    int z = 0;
    char temp;
    for(int i = end + 1; string[i] != 0; i++){
        if(string[i-1] == ' '){
            nstart = i;
        }
        if(string[i+1] == 0 || string[i + 1] == ' '){
            nend = i;
            for(int j = start; j <= end; j++){
                temp = string[j];
                string[j] = string[nstart + z];
                string[nstart + z] = temp;
                z++;
            }
            
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char string[max];
    fgets(string,max,stdin);
    
    string[strlen(string) - 1] = 0; // removing the \n character
    
    int start,end; //start and end of each word
    
    for(int i = 0; string[i] != 0; i++){
        if(i == 0 || string[i-1] == ' '){
            start = i;
        }
        if(i == string[strlen(string)-1] || string[i+1] == ' '){
            end = i;
            swapWords(string, start, end);
        }
    }
    
    
    fputs(string,stdout);
}
```

Comment: Please add your code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: It means you have to shift all the characters between the two words. The direction and offset is determined by the lengths.

Comment: @Sava Majic, Aside: `string[strlen(string) - 1] = 0;` is hacker exploitable.   Consider what happens if the first character read and stored into `string[]` is a null character.

Comment: To chux's point, see [*Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2505965)

Comment: @chux i am not allowed to use strcspn, only allowed functions are strlen, fgets,fputs

Comment: @SavaMajic 1) Restriction like "only allowed functions are strlen, fgets,fputs" deserve to be in the question.   2) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2410359) only uses `strlen()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take `1234567 and ABCD` and `1234 and ABCDEFG`.

1. Rotate the string in the direction of the longer word by the difference in length of the two words. This places the intervening text is in the correct position.

   ```
   1234567 and ABCD             1234 and ABCDEFG
   234567 and ABCD1             G1234 and ABCDEF
   34567 and ABCD12             FG1234 and ABCDE
   4567 and ABCD123             EFG1234 and ABCD
   ```
2. Swap the shorter word with the start of the longer word.

   ```
   4567 and ABCD123             EFG1234 and ABCD
   A567 and 4BCD123             EFGA234 and 1BCD
   AB67 and 45CD123             EFGAB34 and 12CD
   ABC7 and 456D123             EFGABC4 and 123D
   ABCD and 4567123             EFGABCD and 1234
   ```
3. Rotate the longer word in the opposite direction that was used in step 1 until correct.

   ```
   ABCD and 4567123             EFGABCD and 1234
   ABCD and 3456712             FGABCDE and 1234
   ABCD and 2345671             GABCDEF and 1234
   ABCD and 1234567             ABCDEFG and 1234
   ```

If there is text before and/or after the two words, just pretend the string starts and end with the two words. The rest of the string doesn't change.

Comment: I dont think this works if I have a word between ABCD and 1234567, but thanks anyway!

Comment: uh, that's a weird conclusion to which to jump given that there is a word between `ABCD` and `1234567` in my examples (`and`). (Actually, it suffered from the opposite problem. My solution technically *required* some form of intervening text to work. Fixed the wording so this is no longer required.)

Comment: I see now, my bad! Really sorry i am just very tired and didnt think it through.

Answer (score 0):

I made one more solution to this problem:
Example: `ABCD` and `123456`.
`123456` is longer by 2 characters, we can just add 2 space character to the end of the `ABCD` word like this: `ABCD`   then just swap each character like we would if we had two words with the same lenght. After that just remove any 2 consecutive space characters. Here is the code if anyone else has this problem (this only words for 1st and 3rd word but with a bit of tweaking you can make it work for any word combination in the string!):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define max 255
//apple and pear_

void dupeSpace(char* s,int idx,int k){
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        for(int j = strlen(s) + 1; j > idx; j--){
            s[j] = s[j-1];
        }
    }
}
void basicSwap(char* s, int start, int end, int nstart){

    char temp;
    int z = 0;

    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
        temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[nstart + z];
        s[nstart + z] = temp;
        z++;

    }

}


void swapWords(char* s, int start, int end){
    int nstart,nend,nlen,len,cnt,diff;
    cnt = 0;
    len = end - start + 1;

    for(int i = end+1; s[i] != 0;i++){
        if(i == 0 || s[i-1] == ' '){
            nstart = i;
        }
        if(s[i+1] == 0 || s[i + 1] == ' '){
            nend = i;
            ++cnt;
            if(cnt == 2){
                nlen = nend - nstart + 1;
                if(nlen > len){
                    diff = nlen - len;
                    dupeSpace(s,end+1,diff);    //we will remove them later
                    basicSwap(s,start,end,nstart);
                }
                if(len > nlen){
                    diff = len - nlen;
                    dupeSpace(s,nend+1,diff);
                    basicSwap(s,start,end,nstart);
                }
                if(len == nlen){
                    basicSwap(s,start,end,nstart);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
void insertSpace(char* s){

    s[strlen(s)] = ' ';
    s[strlen(s)] = 0;

}

void shiftLeft(char* s, int idx){

    for(int i = idx; s[i] != 0;i++){
        s[i] = s[i+1];
    }

}

void removeExtraSpace(char* s){

    if(s[strlen(s)-1] == ' '){
        s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; s[i] != 0;i++){
        if(s[i] == ' ' && s[i+1] == ' '){
            shiftLeft(s,i);
            i--;
        }
    }

}

int main(){

    char s[max];
    fgets(s,max,stdin);

    s[strlen(s)-1] = 0; // i have been told this is bad practise, but in my case string will never be empty :)
    insertSpace(s); //insert space incase shorter word is at the end of the string, we will remove space later

    int start,end;
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != 0;i++){
        if(i == 0 || s[i-1] == ' '){
            start = i;
        }
        if(s[i+1] == 0 || s[i + 1] == ' '){
            end = i;
            swapWords(s, start, end);
            break;
        }
    }
    removeExtraSpace(s); //removing extra spaces and the one space at the end of the string!
    fputs(s,stdout);
}
```

Comment: This assumes 1) one of the words to swap will always be found at the very end of the string, and 2) there will always be enough extra space in the buffer for the difference in sizes.

Comment: yes, i only made this code to test my idea.

Answer (score 0):

A "general" solution is to recognise that locally reversing each "segment" and then reversing the entire string is a "better" solution. The code can be succinct, using only a few variables and can deal with more than the arbitrary 3 "segments"...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static void rev( char str[], int l, int r ) {
    // conventional "array reversal" logic
    for( r -= 1; l < r; l++, r-- ) {
        char tmp = str[l];
        str[l] = str[r];
        str[r] = tmp;
    }
}

static void doit( char str[] ) {
    int l = 0, r = 0;

    puts( str ); // for demo
    for( ; str[r]; l = r ) {
        while( isalpha( str[r] ) ) r++; // one "word"
        if( r == l ) {
            for( ; str[r]; r++ ) // one "separator"
                if( isalpha( str[r] ) ) // SP or other punct.
                    break;
        }

        rev( str, l, r ); // "local" reversal of word OR separator 
        puts( str ); // for demo
    }

    puts( str ); // for demo
    rev( str, 0, r ); // reverse entire string
    puts( str ); // result
}

int main( void ) {
    char *strs[2] = { // two example strings for demonstration
        "John, Paul, George, Ringo",
        "Apples and Pears",
    };
    int n = sizeof strs/sizeof strs[0];

    while( n-- )
        doit( strs[n] );

    return 0;
}
```

Result

```
Apples and Pears // original
selppA and Pears // 1st word reversed
selppA and Pears // 1st separator reversed (trivial)
selppA dna Pears // 2nd word reversed...
selppA dna Pears
selppA dna sraeP
selppA dna sraeP // entire string ready for reversing
Pears and Apples // result
John, Paul, George, Ringo // original
nhoJ, Paul, George, Ringo // 1st word rev'd
nhoJ ,Paul, George, Ringo // 1st sep rev'd
nhoJ ,luaP, George, Ringo // 2nd word rev'd
nhoJ ,luaP ,George, Ringo // etc....
nhoJ ,luaP ,egroeG, Ringo
nhoJ ,luaP ,egroeG ,Ringo
nhoJ ,luaP ,egroeG ,ogniR
nhoJ ,luaP ,egroeG ,ogniR // entire string ready for reversing
Ringo, George, Paul, John // result
```

NB: As presented, all separators are equivalent.

If the string were "John, Paul George AND Ringo", a bit more code involving tokenising (with an array of pointers) would be required.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was not about reversing the order of the words, just switching the position of 2 words. Your code will just invert the sentence. It only works if we have 3 words and we want to switch 1st and 3rd. Any other case it doesnt.

Comment: @SavaMajic This code _only_ works for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... words (or any other case), reversing the sequence of "words" found in the passed string. Since your question shows only one example of 3 words, I don't know what you're objecting to. Count the lines of code in your answer and, after removing the "demo" output and the test harness, count the lines of code in this answer... Generality with less code is _always_ better than a highly specific solution involving 6 separate functions... The difference is like... like... unh... "Oranges and Apples"